# When querying the registry from a batch file, can I query the Data?

Tags: batch-file, registry

I have the following query -

```
@ECHO OFF
REG QUERY "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft Games\Flight Simulator\10.0" /v AppPath
PAUSE
```

This returns the Name, Type, and Data of the entry, as below -

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft Games\Flight Simulator\10.0
    AppPath    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Games\Microsoft Flight Simulator X\

Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

Is it possible to retrieve only the Data section of a registry entry?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft Games\Flight Simulator\10.0" /v AppPath') do set "AppPath=%%~b"
echo %AppPath%
pause
```

Comment: This causes an infinite loop and crashes the app when I run it.

Comment: Add `skip` to eliminate extra lines in the `reg` output : `for /f "skip=2 tokens=2*"`

Answer (score 1):

Bellow command does work, For example I want to get *OS* name :

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductName ^| findstr "REG_"') do @echo %%b
```

The output is :

```
Windows 10 Enterprise
```

Comment: Simplified version: `for /f "skip=2 tokens=2*" %a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductName') do @echo %b`. Or just `wmic os get Caption`

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for the answer, here an addition to be able then to append a string to a value:

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\...." /v keyname') do set "AppPath=%%~b"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\..." /v "keyname" /f /t REG_SZ /d "%AppPath% appended value"
```