# How to read (Default) value from registry and put into a variable within a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I know there are a lot of questions with reading values from registry, set to a variable in a bat file, but i did not figure out how the read the (default) value?? 
If I use

> Reg.exe QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Notepad++"

I will get

> (Default)  REG_SZ   C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\Notepad++

but if I use the code:

> @echo OFF 
>   Reg.exe QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Notepad++" 
>   setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
>   FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1-3" %%A IN ('Reg QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Notepad++" ') DO (   
>       set ValueType=%%B
>       set ValueValue=%%C
>   )
>   if defined ValueType(   
>       @echo Value Type = %ValueType%
>       @echo Value Value = %ValueValue%
>   ) else (
>       @echo not found.
>   )

I get the error: "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

What I want is to put into ValueValue = C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\Notepad++

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the cmd line:

```
for /f "tokens=3*" %a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Notepad++"') do echo %a %b
```

if you want to do it in script, double the %'s

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581078/batch-reg-query-return-just-data - This example write to a variable